# Singleton in .NET shared across all sessions?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, singleton

I am creating a singleton to hold a linqtoumbraco datacontext which pulls data from a cached xml file.

I understand how to create a singleton class and to use locks to prevent new threads from creating new instances.

I don't understand multithreading and how .NET sessions work too well and want to know if I create the singleton as described above, will it be shared by all users who hit my web app while the app pool remains alive?  In other words, the singleton is not just a singleton for one user session, it is for all sessions?

Thanks

Comment: Singletons in C# should not require locks.

Comment: To Kirk Woll's comment [this article form Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) should be required reading before implementing your first C# singleton.

Comment: @ConradFrix The useful article linked in your comment has moved and can now be found at [new location of Jon Skeet article on singletons](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it will be, static members are shared for whole ASP.Net application

Another way to do this, to create and assign datacontext in HttpContext.Current.Application, and you can get it from anywhere you want in any session

But think about it a bit, are  all clients only read from xml file? what if one client is reading in the time the other writing? Or are that datacontext supports multithread reading?
You should answer all this questions before using that datacontext in static manner

Comment: Within a single worker process, that is true. However, a single application may use multiple worker processes, in which case each one has its own instance of the singleton.

Comment: Yes, it will be read only for the datacontext - I am not using the datacontext for inserts and updates. I'll have to refresh the xml cache when new data is written or updated.

Comment: Than try one of methods I suggest @user718012

Answer (score 0):

If you store it in a normal static field then yes, it will be shared. You can place the [ThreadStatic] Attribute on the field to tie it to the current thread. Keep in mind that threads can be reused so you'll want to null out the field when you are done with it.

Comment: Don't use ThreadStatic in asp.net, the thread may be reused for multiple requests in unpredictable ways, there is no guarantee that a single request is served by a single thread

Comment: Asp.net [does not guarantee](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html) per-session thread affinity, so it would be unwise to use ThreadStatic for this purpose in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the server instance is alive your singleton will be one shared across the entire app, it's like stuff you initialize on global.asax when server start